# How to retrieve an output from a Github publish Action

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to retrieve the output from a publish Azure action called: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
( https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy )
But for some reason that I don't understand I'm unable to retrieve the output for the webapp-url that the action is supposed to provide me. But for some reason no matter what I do I always get a null value.

```
- name: Deploy to Azure Web App Staging
  uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
  id: deploy_webapp
  with:
    app-name: 'asev3-webApp-streams'
    slot-name: 'integ'
    publish-profile: ${{ secrets.WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
    package: poc-webapp-streams\Streams.WebApi.${{ github.run_number }}.zip

- name: Check WebApp Health
  uses: jtalk/url-health-check-action@v1.5
  with:
    # Check the following URLs one by one sequentially
    url: ${{ steps.deploy_webapp.output.webapp-url }}/api/v1/status
```

Comment: To use the output you should first set it. Example: https://gist.github.com/weibeld/b8db6a1201ca54d33d6b35147a0c5509
Where did you set the `webapp-url` value? I doesn't seem to be done through the action.

Comment: I didn't set it because i thought that the Actions enables that Output. Here is the action.yaml for that Action:https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy/blob/master/action.yml
 
```
outputs:
  webapp-url:
    description: 'URL to work with your webapp'
```

Comment: You're right, I found it now at the end of this file: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy/blob/master/src/DeploymentProvider/Providers/WebAppDeploymentProvider.ts Did you check if the deployment was successful after using the action? (an intern error could prevent the output to be saved).

Comment: Ya it was successful, I got a full environment with App Services

Comment: After a few more researches, I observed there is a `azure-app-service-settings action`: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-app-service-settings#sample-workflow-to-configure-settings-on-an-azure-web-app that could also return the `webapp-url` as output. But it uses `outputs` with an `s` at the end to get the value. Did you try using `steps.deploy_webapp.outputs.webapp-url` ?

Comment: Ya I did, it came up as null, I open a ticket for Github Support and they are checking it out. If I get an answer I will post back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well at the end i solved this issue in the following way:

```
- name: Deploy to WebApp slot Integ
  uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
  id: deploy
  with:
    app-name: 'poc-asev3-webApp-streamsBack'
    slot-name: 'integ'
    publish-profile: ${{ secrets.WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
    package: ${{ steps.package_path.outputs.PACKAGE }}

- name: Check WebApp Health
  uses: jtalk/url-health-check-action@v1.5
  with:
    url: ${{ steps.deploy.outputs.webapp-url }}/${{ github.event.inputs.healthcheck }}
```

My mistake that I used output instead of outputs, capital S. in the URL: section of the last action.